# ¿Como puedo recibir los datos que envio mediante fetch (JS) en un PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, fetch

Envié un objeto mediante fetch desde JavaScript, pero cunado intento obtener los datos en mi archivo PHP e insertarlos en mi base de datos MySQL, simplemente no se inserta ningún dato.

Así es como estoy enviando los datos (un objeto) mediante fetch:

> app.js

```javascript
function sendProm(){
    fetch("../be/be_saveAvg.php" , {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(window.textContentProm),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }    
    })
    .then((res) => console.log(res.json()))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
};
```

Investigando encontré que los datos se podrían obtener así:

> be_saveAvg.php

```php
include "be_connection.php";

$promedio = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);

$insertProm = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO promedios(promedio) VALUES ('$promedio[0]')");
```

*El archivo "be_connection.php" solo contiene la conexión a la base de datos*

Comment: Perdón si cometí algún error en cuanto a la pregunta, es la primera que hago en el foro :)

Comment: Muestra cómo envías los datos y también cómo los estás intentando leer en el archivo PHP. Lo que muestras no es suficiente para poder detectar el problema. Adicionalmente mira [ask] y realiza el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, obtuve mi primer medalla y reformulé la pregunta